# Modifying roles for user management in Laravel 8x with Livewire

Tags: laravel

What I am trying to do is add the adding user's section from the Team Settings page into a CRUD which I made, what I have been able to do is add the ability to edit the data but not pass over the role management side (see image here:)

[image: This is what I am wanting to have on CRUD section]

I have a form which I made to add new Users, is there some code which I can fully copy paste already existing inside the Laravel JetStream solution to achieve adding users. See image:

[image: What I have]

Once I have the above sorted I will be able to work out the edit myself :)

Code I need to snip:

@if (Gate::check('addTeamMember', $team))

```
<!-- Add Team Member -->
<div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
    <x-jet-form-section submit="addTeamMember">
        <x-slot name="title">
            {{ __('Add Team Member') }}
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="description">
            {{ __('Add a new team member to your team, allowing them to collaborate with you.') }}
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="form">
            <div class="col-span-6">
                <div class="max-w-xl text-sm text-gray-600">
                    {{ __('Please provide the email address of the person you would like to add to this team. The email address must be associated with an existing account.') }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Member Email -->
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
                <x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="addTeamMemberForm.email" />
                <x-jet-input-error for="email" class="mt-2" />
            </div>

            <!-- Role -->
            @if (count($this->roles) > 0)
                <div class="col-span-6 lg:col-span-4">
                    <x-jet-label for="role" value="{{ __('Role') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input-error for="role" class="mt-2" />

                    <div class="mt-1 border border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
                        @foreach ($this->roles as $index => $role)
                                <div class="px-4 py-3 {{ $index > 0 ? 'border-t border-gray-200' : '' }}"
                                                wire:click="$set('addTeamMemberForm.role', '{{ $role->key }}')">
                                    <div class="{{ isset($addTeamMemberForm['role']) && $addTeamMemberForm['role'] !== $role->key ? 'opacity-50' : '' }}">
                                        <!-- Role Name -->
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 {{ $addTeamMemberForm['role'] == $role->key ? 'font-semibold' : '' }}">
                                                {{ $role->name }}
                                            </div>

                                            @if ($addTeamMemberForm['role'] == $role->key)
                                                <svg class="ml-2 h-5 w-5 text-green-400" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Role Description -->
                                        <div class="mt-2 text-xs text-gray-600">
                                            {{ $role->description }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="actions">
            <x-jet-action-message class="mr-3" on="saved">
                {{ __('Added.') }}
            </x-jet-action-message>

            <x-jet-button>
                {{ __('Add') }}
            </x-jet-button>
        </x-slot>
    </x-jet-form-section>
</div>
```

@endif

Comment: I'm working on the same issue. However, instead of creating a separate form, I'm trying to figure out how to modify the gate check so that users with addteammember permissions (admins, by default) will see the default form that you show above. I really think it's a matter of modifying the rules in the gate and once that's resolved, it should just work.

Comment: NB: at present, by default, Jetstream only allows team owners to add users to their team. This is managed by gate / policy in `app\Policies\TeamPolicy::addTeamMember`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to publish the Jetstream views, if you haven't done so already:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views`

In your existing blade file (the one you are using for user management), you should be able to include that exact view using something like:

`@livewire('teams.team-member-manager')`

Do note: this is a Livewire component. If you are using the Vue version, you'll need to check [the documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/teams.html#member-management-views-pages) on how to include that instead.

And as I mentioned in a comment above, you may need to modify `app/Policies/TeamPolicy::addTeamMember` to suit your needs. If you'd rather not change the default policies, you may also be able to [intercept a gate check](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks), but that's beyond my level of expertise at this late hour and left as an exercise for the reader.

HTH